# How to offset the center of a Google maps (API v3) in pixels?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was wondering if it is possible to **offset the center** of a map in Google maps api v3. I would like to control this offset in **pixels**, since by lat and lng seems wrong and very difficult to predict.

I just need to place a marker, and then offset the center by 250px so I can place some other content in the middle of the map.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Found this question when researching and thought I should provide an answer:

```js
function map_recenter(latlng,offsetx,offsety) {
    var point1 = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(
        (latlng instanceof google.maps.LatLng) ? latlng : map.getCenter()
    );
    var point2 = new google.maps.Point(
        ( (typeof(offsetx) == 'number' ? offsetx : 0) / Math.pow(2, map.getZoom()) ) || 0,
        ( (typeof(offsety) == 'number' ? offsety : 0) / Math.pow(2, map.getZoom()) ) || 0
    );  
    map.setCenter(map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(
        point1.x - point2.x,
        point1.y + point2.y
    )));
}
```

If your Google maps variable isn't `map` use the following call function reference:

```js
function map_recenter(map,latlng,offsetx,offsety) { ...
```

Comment: I'm using it on onMarkerClick(). When I click over a Mark works perfect, but if I fire the Mark (from code) with google.maps.event.trigger(thisMark, 'click'); don't work... but no matters (I can live with that)... It's the best solution to do offset. Thanks!!!

Comment: Beautiful and elegant solution.

Comment: This function should be called after projection_changed event has fired otherwise map.getProjection() call would throw a js error. google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,"projection_changed", function() {
   map_recenter(...);
 });

Comment: if I use Math.pow(2, this.map.getCameraZoom() the displacement is very small, why?

Comment: This works well, but is there a way to modify it to use panTo instead of setCenter? Would be nice if it transitioned rather than jumped.

Answer (score 23):

Refer to this question: [How to offset the center of a Google maps (API v3) in pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538681/how-to-call-fromlatlngtodivpixel-in-google-maps-api-v3/7018754#7018754)

This is a modification of an answer I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146676/google-maps-api-v3-offset-panto-by-x-pixels/12608127#12608127).

```
google.maps.Map.prototype.setCenterWithOffset= function(latlng, offsetX, offsetY) {
    var map = this;
    var ov = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    ov.onAdd = function() {
        var proj = this.getProjection();
        var aPoint = proj.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(latlng);
        aPoint.x = aPoint.x+offsetX;
        aPoint.y = aPoint.y+offsetY;
        map.setCenter(proj.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(aPoint));
    }; 
    ov.draw = function() {}; 
    ov.setMap(this); 
};
```

You can then just use it like so:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: latlng
});

map.setCenterWithOffset(latlng, 0, 250);
```

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/YGzdW/3/).

Comment: Im currently using an iFrame to load my map on page, it comes with a nice white background box of information about the point of interest, is this achievable with the projection method?

Answer (score 8):

there's also the panBy method of the map object... you can offset by a specified number of pixels.  However, you'll get a smooth transition animation, which may not be what you wanted.  I'm looking for the same thing myself, will let you know what I find.

Comment: yep, `map.panBy(0,-10)` to move it up per 10px

Comment: this should be the answer, much simpler than the others

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the MapCanvasProjection object - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapCanvasProjection

You can get the map center latLng (map.getCenter()) then convert that to the container pixel coordinates with fromContainerPixeltoLatLng()

Comment: Is it possible to do this without rendering the map and then redrawing it, i.e. without the user seeing a jump?

Answer (score 0):

Example for latitude offset to pan a bit lower (on a negative lat, idk if positive lat will give the same result)

```
map.setZoom(15);
let latV = e.latLng.lat()+0.0135;
let lngV = e.latLng.lng();
map.panTo({lat: latV, lng: lngV});
```