# How to offset the center point in Google maps api V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map with a semi transparent panel covering a portion of the area. I would like to adjust the center point of the map to take into account the portion of the map that is partially obscured. See the image below. Ideally, where the crosshairs and pin are placed would be the center point of the map.

I hope that makes sense.

The reason is simple: When you zoom it needs to center the map over the crosshair rather than at 50% 50%. Also, I will be plotting markers on the map and moving through them in sequence. When the map centers on them, they also need to be at the offset position.

[image: Mockup of the map I am building]

Comment: You are going to have to clarify your question. What does "take into account the portion of the map that is partially obscured" mean? And what does "rather than at 50% 50%" mean? Want to help, but can't figure out what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, Can you please give the url of working example because i need some help for creating a moving ploy line along with route line

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is not particularly difficult once you find [the relevant previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674392/how-to-access-google-maps-api-v3-markers-div-and-its-pixel-position).

You need to convert the centre of the map to its world co-ordinates, find where the map needs to be centered to put the *apparent* centre where you want it, and re-centre the map using the *real* centre.

The API will always centre the map on the centre of the viewport, so you need to be careful if you use `map.getCenter()` as it will return the real centre, not the apparent centre. I suppose it would be possible to overload the API so that its `getCenter()` and `setCenter()` methods are replaced, but I haven't done that.

Code below. [Example online](http://acleach.me.uk/gmaps/v3/map-offsetcentre.htm). In the example, clicking the button shifts the centre of the map (there's a road junction there) down 100px and left 200px.

```
function offsetCenter(latlng, offsetx, offsety) {

    // latlng is the apparent centre-point
    // offsetx is the distance you want that point to move to the right, in pixels
    // offsety is the distance you want that point to move upwards, in pixels
    // offset can be negative
    // offsetx and offsety are both optional

    var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());

    var worldCoordinateCenter = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latlng);
    var pixelOffset = new google.maps.Point((offsetx/scale) || 0,(offsety/scale) ||0);

    var worldCoordinateNewCenter = new google.maps.Point(
        worldCoordinateCenter.x - pixelOffset.x,
        worldCoordinateCenter.y + pixelOffset.y
    );

    var newCenter = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(worldCoordinateNewCenter);

    map.setCenter(newCenter);

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get this code to fire when the page loads so that the map shows as offset when first viewed?

Comment: @DarrenCook: Of course. Just use this instead of `map.setCenter()`. All this code does is recalculate what the map is told do do, and then it does its own `map.setCenter()`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, so in my code I took addMarkerFromAdress(latLng, title) and replaced with function offsetCenter(latlng,offsetx,offsety) and it all still works - but how do I get the value for offsety (243px) into the function?

Comment: Better use `map.panBy(250, 0);`

Comment: @AlexanderShvetsov `panBy` moves the map, which may not be desirable. The `offsetCenter` function doesn't do that; it provides a direct replacement for `setCenter` without panning the map.

Comment: I found that the `nw` var is never used by this script and at least in my use case could be removed without any issue.  I didn't try this by itself though since i have a bunch of other methods already setting the bounds and all that.

Comment: I had issues with getProjection(). Found this better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12608699/457850 which works first go

Comment: I'd say the reason's for issues with getProjection is the variable `map` not being defined - this code seems to assume `map` has been set to the google maps instance in the scope the function is defined in. I added `map` as a parameter (as there are multiple maps coexisting in our solution) and passed it with the function.

Comment: @AndrewLeach after trying your code, I think you're flipping the sign on the offset.y.  For me I also have to subtract it if I want to push the center down by a certain number of pixels.

Comment: @BenM. "clicking the button shifts the centre of the map (there's a road junction there) down 100px and left 200px." That's intended, and it still happens.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I see what you're saying, I guess "down" to mean would mean that the latitude would decrease.  In your example, If I start zoomed in on Sheffield Green, after a few button clicks I'm at Crowborough, which is NW of Sheffield Green (which to me is "up" and "right") but I can understand that you're saying the map is going "down and left".

Comment: Hello, I tried to copy your code for the cordova google maps plugin but every time I call this method when the user presses a 'center' button it gives me a different position. I just want the center of the map to be upper so the user's position marker is nearer the bottom of the screen for when he navigates. Also, it doesn't work for me if I use the 'scale' variable My code is this, help please: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/2551#issuecomment-458087325

Comment: Awesome Andrew 

Comment: Hi, I am working on something similar. I have one question though, how do I get the latlng of the apparent center of the map, I am centering that marker using css and only have offset values in px. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 77):

Also take a look at the panBy(x:number, y:number) function on the maps object.

The documentation mentions this about the function:

> Changes the center of the map by the given distance in pixels. If the distance is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated. Note that the map coordinate system increases from west to east (for x values) and north to south (for y values).

Just use it like this:

```
mapsObject.panBy(200, 100)
```

Comment: Anybody know of a way to disable animation for this method always?

Comment: This must be the answer. It worked perfectly and so easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Here's an example of solving the problem using `panBy()` method of the maps API: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/2wej9smf/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/rat1fkkc/   here is my answer edited similar to mr upside down

Answer (score 12):

Just found another simplest solution.
In case you're using fitBounds method, you can pass optional second argument to its. This argument is padding, that will be considered while fitting bounds.

```
// pass single side:
map.fitBounds(bounds, { left: 1000 })

// OR use Number:
map.fitBounds(bounds, 20)
```

Further reading: [official docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/map#Map.fitBounds).

Comment: this is perfect!

Comment: Easiest solution

Answer (score 9):

Here's a simpler method that might be more useful in responsive design since you can use percentages instead of pixels. No world coordinates, no LatLngs to Points!

```
var center;  // a latLng
var offsetX = 0.25; // move center one quarter map width left
var offsetY = 0.25; // move center one quarter map height down

var span = map.getBounds().toSpan(); // a latLng - # of deg map spans

var newCenter = { 
    lat: center.lat() + span.lat()*offsetY,
    lng: center.lng() + span.lng()*offsetX
};

map.panTo(newCenter);  // or map.setCenter(newCenter);
```

Comment: Tried this on InfoBox and it works! (although the pixelOffset still needs to be fixed)

Comment: Great answer for both the simplicity of the solution AND taking responsive design into consideration

Comment: I get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toSpan' of undefined

Comment: can we get the newCenter lat long ?

Comment: This would not work if there is a need to change the zoom in the same operation. Also, it would not work accurately if the destination (new) center is located geographically far from the current center. Even at the same zoom level, 0.25 of the width of the screen represents a different distance at the equator than in Norway, for example, due to the Mercator projection used. Projecting the final coordinates is more robust.

Answer (score 6):

Andrew's is the answer. However, in my case, map.getBounds() kept returning undefined. I fixed it waiting for the bounds_changed event and *then* call the function to offset the center. Like so:

```
var center_moved = false;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
  if(!center_moved){
    offsetCenter(map.getCenter(), 250, -200);
    center_moved = true; 
  }
});
```

Comment: This answer in combination with (placed after) Andrew's answer was the solution for me. Thank you Nahuel!

Answer (score 4):

Old question, I know. But how about a more CSS-centric way?

http://codepen.io/eddyblair/pen/VjpNQQ

What I did was:

- Wrap the map and overlay in a container with `overflow: hidden`
- Overlaid the overlay with `position: absolute`
- Extended the map's *apparent width* by the overlay width (plus any padding and offset) by setting a negative `margin-left`.
- Then in order to comply with https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html positioned the widgets and attribution `div`s.

This way the centre of the map lies in line with the centre of the desired area. The js is just standard map js.

Repositioning the icons for street-view is an exercise for the reader :)

---

If you want the overlay on the left, just change line `24` `margin-left` to `margin-right` and line 32 `right` to `left`.

Comment: I really like this approach.  Keeps the Angular/javascript nice and clean.

Comment: Thanks :) This will, of course, need updating whenever google change their styles. I put comments before the CSS which moves the attributions and controls etc.. which should give an idea of how I did it if it does need modifying. Additional CSS will need creating to sort out street view.

Answer (score 3):

After extensive searching I could not find a way to do this that also included zoom. Thankfully a [clever chap](https://www.reonomy.com/offsetting-bounds-and-zoom-on-a-google-map/) has figured it out.  There is also a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vh3s88mc/15/)

```js
'use strict';

const TILE_SIZE = {
  height: 256,
  width: 256
}; // google World tile size, as of v3.22
const ZOOM_MAX = 21; // max google maps zoom level, as of v3.22
const BUFFER = 15; // edge buffer for fitting markers within viewport bounds

const mapOptions = {
  zoom: 14,
  center: {
    lat: 34.075328,
    lng: -118.330432
  },
  options: {
    mapTypeControl: false
  }
};
const markers = [];
const mapDimensions = {};
const mapOffset = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
const mapEl = document.getElementById('gmap');
const overlayEl = document.getElementById('overlay');
const gmap = new google.maps.Map(mapEl, mapOptions);

const updateMapDimensions = () => {
  mapDimensions.height = mapEl.offsetHeight;
  mapDimensions.width = mapEl.offsetWidth;
};

const getBoundsZoomLevel = (bounds, dimensions) => {
  const latRadian = lat => {
    let sin = Math.sin(lat * Math.PI / 180);
    let radX2 = Math.log((1 + sin) / (1 - sin)) / 2;
    return Math.max(Math.min(radX2, Math.PI), -Math.PI) / 2;
  };
  const zoom = (mapPx, worldPx, fraction) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.log(mapPx / worldPx / fraction) / Math.LN2);
  };
  const ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
  const sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
  const latFraction = (latRadian(ne.lat()) - latRadian(sw.lat())) / Math.PI;
  const lngDiff = ne.lng() - sw.lng();
  const lngFraction = ((lngDiff < 0) ? (lngDiff + 360) : lngDiff) / 360;
  const latZoom = zoom(dimensions.height, TILE_SIZE.height, latFraction);
  const lngZoom = zoom(dimensions.width, TILE_SIZE.width, lngFraction);
  return Math.min(latZoom, lngZoom, ZOOM_MAX);
};

const getBounds = locations => {
  let northeastLat;
  let northeastLong;
  let southwestLat;
  let southwestLong;
  locations.forEach(function(location) {
    if (!northeastLat) {
      northeastLat = southwestLat = location.lat;
      southwestLong = northeastLong = location.lng;
      return;
    }
    if (location.lat > northeastLat) northeastLat = location.lat;
    else if (location.lat < southwestLat) southwestLat = location.lat;
    if (location.lng < northeastLong) northeastLong = location.lng;
    else if (location.lng > southwestLong) southwestLong = location.lng;
  });
  const northeast = new google.maps.LatLng(northeastLat, northeastLong);
  const southwest = new google.maps.LatLng(southwestLat, southwestLong);
  const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  bounds.extend(northeast);
  bounds.extend(southwest);
  return bounds;
};

const zoomWithOffset = shouldZoom => {
  const currentzoom = gmap.getZoom();
  const newzoom = shouldZoom ? currentzoom + 1 : currentzoom - 1;
  const offset = {
    x: shouldZoom ? -mapOffset.x / 4 : mapOffset.x / 2,
    y: shouldZoom ? -mapOffset.y / 4 : mapOffset.y / 2
  };
  const newCenter = offsetLatLng(gmap.getCenter(), offset.x, offset.y);
  if (shouldZoom) {
    gmap.setZoom(newzoom);
    gmap.panTo(newCenter);
  } else {
    gmap.setCenter(newCenter);
    gmap.setZoom(newzoom);
  }
};

const setMapBounds = locations => {
  updateMapDimensions();
  const bounds = getBounds(locations);
  const dimensions = {
    width: mapDimensions.width - mapOffset.x - BUFFER * 2,
    height: mapDimensions.height - mapOffset.y - BUFFER * 2
  };
  const zoomLevel = getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds, dimensions);
  gmap.setZoom(zoomLevel);
  setOffsetCenter(bounds.getCenter());
};

const offsetLatLng = (latlng, offsetX, offsetY) => {
  offsetX = offsetX || 0;
  offsetY = offsetY || 0;
  const scale = Math.pow(2, gmap.getZoom());
  const point = gmap.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latlng);
  const pixelOffset = new google.maps.Point((offsetX / scale), (offsetY / scale));
  const newPoint = new google.maps.Point(
    point.x - pixelOffset.x,
    point.y + pixelOffset.y
  );
  return gmap.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(newPoint);
};

const setOffsetCenter = latlng => {
  const newCenterLatLng = offsetLatLng(latlng, mapOffset.x / 2, mapOffset.y / 2);
  gmap.panTo(newCenterLatLng);
};

const locations = [{
  name: 'Wilshire Country Club',
  lat: 34.077796,
  lng: -118.331151
}, {
  name: '301 N Rossmore Ave',
  lat: 34.077146,
  lng: -118.327805
}, {
  name: '5920 Beverly Blvd',
  lat: 34.070281,
  lng: -118.331831
}];

locations.forEach(function(location) {
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng),
    title: location.name
  })
  marker.setMap(gmap);
  markers.push(marker);
});

mapOffset.x = overlayEl.offsetWidth;

document.zoom = bool => zoomWithOffset(bool);
document.setBounds = () => setMapBounds(locations);
```

```css
section {
  height: 180px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: grey;
}
figure {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
gmap {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<section>
  <figure>
    <gmap id="gmap"></gmap>
    <figcaption id="overlay">
      <h4>Tile Overlay</h4>
      <p>To be avoided by the map!</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
<button onclick="zoom(true)">zoom in</button>
<button onclick="zoom(false)">zoom out</button>
<button onclick="setBounds()">set bounds</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach when it comes to offsetting a route or a group of markers can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26192440/1238965

It still uses the `fromLatLngToPoint()` method described in @Andrew Leach answer.

Comment: This is more sophisticated than the accepted answer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of **SIMPLE** use for:

- for **DESKTOP** version when the **left side** is **OVERLAY** with a width of `500`
- for the **MOBILE** version when **the bottom** of the page is **OVERLAY** with a height of `250`

The solution will also work smoothly when the screen size changes live.

Requires that **query** be defined in **css** with `@media screen and (min-width: 1025px)` and `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)`

Code:

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 13
    });

    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    // add markers to bounds

    // Initial bounds
    defineBounds()

    // Trigger resize browser and set new bounds
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        defineBounds()
    });
}

function defineBounds() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width:1025px)").matches) {
        map.fitBounds(bounds, {
            top: 100,
            right: 100,
            left: 600, // 500 + 100
            bottom: 100
        });
    } else {
        map.fitBounds(bounds, {
            top: 80,
            right: 80,
            left: 80,
            bottom: 330 // 250 + 80
        });
    }
}
```

The solution can be customized for OVERLAY located on each side of the screen