# Focus Google Maps marker to the left

Tags: google-maps

I probably don't know the keywords to search, and am not able to google for a solution so far.

Let's say a map div is 200px x 200px (width x height). When we display Google Maps, the map is automatically centered, where the marker is at the center of the map, roughly the marker appear at 100px x 100px coordinates.

How can I move the map to show the marker 20px from left, say 20px x 100px coordinates?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to offset the center point in Google maps api V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656743/how-to-offset-the-center-point-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stupid me. The `center` in map options suffices:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

```
var centerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(100.0001, 90.001 + 0.003);
var myOptions = {
  center: centerLatLng,
};
```

The `+ 0.003` will align the focus to the left horizontally. Play around with the coordinates to align the focus.