# Maintain center of google map when I change the size of the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to change the size of a map and maintain the center. It doesn't work thoug. Code

```
var center = map.getCenter()
$('#left').css("width", "360px");
map.setCenter(center)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the accepted answer in this question: [How to offset the center point in Google maps api V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656743/how-to-offset-the-center-point-in-google-maps-api-v3)

What you need to do is work out how far the centre-point of the map will need to be moved so it's where it was before the re-size, and then call my new `offsetCenter` function to put it back there.

For example: resizing a map so that the left edge moves 300px to the left will require your centre-point to appear 150px to the right of the real centre.

```
var center = map.getCenter();
$('#left').css("width", "360px");
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
offsetCenter(center,150,0);
```

Comment: Hrm, I was playing around with your function and it seems to do what I want if I pass offsetCenter(center,0,0);