# How to fix bottom of layout of 100% height (jQuery Mobile and Google Map)?

Tags: css, html, google-maps, layout

I have a layout where I would like the main content area to be 100% height of the remaining space. So I am almost there but the bottom is truncated (which effects zoom and centering). There is 41px from the bottom that is being truncated, which is the measurement of the header area: http://jsfiddle.net/GTscW/

The reason why I know if it cut off is because I do not see the Google map copyright info. Here is the not truncated, but truncates the top (I just removed the top: 41px from #content  .inner-content): http://jsfiddle.net/GTscW/1/

How do I subtract 41px from the bottom from the first sample to get the content 100% of the remaining area?

**EDIT:**

I was able to add just this: $('#content .inner-content').height($(this).height() - $('#header').height()), but really no CSS solution though???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that it's not easy to mix percentages and pixel measurements, because different screen sizes will behave differently. But it is possible to use API features to get the map to behave the way you want it to, on any size screen.

Make the map 100% of the screen size, so the header obscures part of the map. Suppress the default map controls so they do not appear partially obscured. Create an empty custom control the same size as the header and position it at the top of the map. When the map controls are added back, the custom control pushes them out of their usual place so they look right on the visible map.

```
var posn=google.maps.ControlPosition; // shorten the reference

// Add empty custom control
var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');
controlDiv.style.width='100%';
controlDiv.style.height='41px';
map.controls[posn.TOP_LEFT].push(controlDiv);
map.controls[posn.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlDiv);

// Add map controls
map.setOptions({
    mapTypeControlOptions:{position:posn.RIGHT_TOP},
    mapTypeControl:true,
    panControlOptions:{position:posn.LEFT_TOP},
    panControl:true,
    streetViewControlOptions:{position:posn.LEFT_TOP},
    streetViewControl:true,
    zoomControlOptions:{position:posn.LEFT_TOP},
    zoomControl:true
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GTscW/4/

Note 1: Because the map is actually 41px larger than it looks (in your case), the centre-point will be 20px higher than the centre of the viewable map. This may not be worth worrying about. If it is, then dealing with an apparent centre-point is the subject of [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656743/how-to-offset-the-center-point-in-google-maps-api-v3/10666030#10666030).

Note 2: This method won't work to get a fixed *footer,* because the Google logo and Terms links are always at the bottom of the map and [currently] don't move to avoid a control.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your fiddle with a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/T2Nkk/

Basically, create a function that looks something like this:

```
function remainder() {
    $("*[height=\"remainder\"]").each(function(index, element) {
        var offsetParent;
        var target = $(element);
        if (element==$("body")[0]) {
            offsetParent = $("html");
        }
        else {
            offsetParent = target.offsetParent();
        }
        var position = target.position();
        var heightParent = offsetParent.height();
        var extras = target.outerHeight(true)-target.height();
        var remainderHeight = heightParent-position.top;
        target.height(remainderHeight-extras);
    });
}
```

For the element that you want to occupy the remainder of the page, do this:

```
<div id="content" data-role="content" height="remainder">
```

Finally, when your document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    remainder();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In css only you can try to use a trick : use both `top` and `bottom` attributes on `position: absolute` property like I did on your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GTscW/23/

Don't know if it works everywhere though.