# jquery, javascript: adjusting the center/window position of google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to figure out how to adjust the window view or center position of google maps api. I have a google maps api with width 100% and height 100%, so it covers the whole screen and its supposed to be used as background for information so this allows me to have a list of items to display. Example is how [foursquare](https://foursquare.com/explore?near=Los%20Angeles,%20CA&q=food) does it. I want to be able to do something like that, display a list of items on the side and have the window area be next to it.

I hope i'm explaining this clearly?

Thanks!

Comment: See this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656743/how-to-offset-the-center-point-in-google-maps-api-v3) It may be what you are looking for