# Adding padding to Google Maps fitBounds and other positioning methods

Tags: google-maps, padding

I have a google map as page background and a few div layers above it. When I place markers on the map I would like to be placed in the visible part of the map, not below the divs. In other words.. I need to add padding to the map so the functions like fitBounds(), setCenter() and etc. to position the markers in the visible part of the map.

There are many examples around but none of them looks quite well or it is working at all. Most of them are similar to:

1. I have tried to calculate the bounds and to extend bounds with some padding but it is a two step process. At first.. the map is positioned at original bounds to get the correct projection and then it is animated to the extended bounds. It doesnt look professional, we have two `fitBounds()` and the second one is animated. http://jsfiddle.net/seddass/CuKTK/
2. I have tried to add custom control to my map but it seems that the custom controls doesnt add padding to the map as suggested on many places. http://jsfiddle.net/seddass/wtT3t/1/

Can anyone can provide a working example or a better solution for padding to for Google Map v3? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related question: [How to offset the center point in Google maps api V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656743/how-to-offset-the-center-point-in-google-maps-api-v3)