# map.panby(x,y) where to place in google map code

Tags: google-maps

Since days I tried to find the right place again and again but without any luck.
I can't find out where to place the `map.panby ( x , y )`in my following google maps code to get the marker a bot more on the right.

It would be great if someone could help me!

Best

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var geocoder;
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5200066, 13.404954);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 6,
          scrollwheel: false,
          navigationControl: false,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          scaleControl: false,
          draggable: false,
          zoomControl: true,
          zoomControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
         },
          streetViewControl:false,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          styles: [
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.country",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      { "weight": 1.2 },
      { "color": "#dd4b39" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "simplified" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "administrative.country",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  }
]
}

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('user-map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      }

       function showAddress(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Adresse konnte aus folgendem Grund nicht gefunden werden: " + status);
      }



      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { // Add a Click Listener to our marker 
    window.location='/freiwillige/?s=<?php echo $country ?>'; // URL to Link Marker to (i.e Google Places Listing)
});
    });

  }      

  jQuery(document).ready( function() { initialize(); showAddress('<?php echo $address ?>'); } );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to place panby at any point after the instantiation of the map, so in the example you have given:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('user-map-canvas'), mapOptions);
map.panby(x, y);
```

Should work perfectly.

Note that this function pans the map, it doesn't move the marker relative to the tiles, I presume this is what you intended?

*Edit* You should be able to place the call at any point in execution. So for example to offset the map slightly after your geocode request you could do:

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
    map.panby(x, y);
  }
```

*edit* Ok so I've modified your original code with the changes I've mentioned. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        draggable: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
        },
        streetViewControl:false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [
        {
            "featureType": "administrative.country",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
            { "weight": 1.2 },
            { "color": "#dd4b39" }
            ]
        },{
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "simplified" }
            ]
        },{
            "featureType": "administrative.country",
            "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "on" }
            ]
        },{
            "featureType": "administrative.locality",
            "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "on" }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('user-map-canvas'), mapOptions);   
    }

    function showAddress(address) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.panby(x, y);
            } 
            else 
            {
                alert("Adresse konnte aus folgendem Grund nicht gefunden werden: " + status);
            }



            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { // Add a Click Listener to our marker 
                window.location='/freiwillige/?s=<?php echo $country ?>'; // URL to Link Marker to (i.e Google Places Listing)
            });
        });

    }      

    jQuery(document).ready( function() { initialize(); showAddress('<?php echo $address ?>'); } );
</script>
```

I've removed the original centering of the map (and the variable latlng, you don't use it anywhere else) and then centered and offset after the geocode request completes. Fingers. Crossed.

*Edit* See answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656743/how-to-offset-the-center-point-in-google-maps-api-v3) if panby still isn't working, but I can't see any issues with the code.

Comment: Wow! That brought me a big step further! Thanks... :)
But now the map centers at the point defined here: `var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5200066, 13.404954);` instead of the marker.
Is there a way to fix that, too.

Comment: Do you want the map to center to the marker on initialize or after the geocode request?

Comment: Well, I just want to reach that it centers to the marker when loading the page but the marker should be a bit to the right. ;)
Thank you very much, this is going to make me crazy!

Comment: See the second edit above, any help there? Sorry I wasn't clear on what you were trying to do.

Comment: Ok I tried it and went lost. First of all thank you again for your help. But that doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure about what to move where.

Comment: Ok I've edited the complete code so you can see what I meant.

Comment: Great! But sadly it's still the same. The marker gets centered to the middle of the map. And I edited the x and y of cause... :(

Comment: How far are you panning (with x and y), see edit for similar question with more complex solution.