# google maps api fitbound with offset?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fitbounds

I have a google map with a custom control over it, covering 35% of the right area:

```
  var myControl = document.getElementById('tireshopsPickerList');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push(myControl);
```

When the user enter an address in an input box above the map I geocode it and build a list of shops nearby; I place markers and then I currently use fitbounds to secure the first 5 shops are visible on the map:

```
      var fullBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      _.each(
        _.first(shops, 5),
        function (s) {
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(s.shop.latitude),
            parseFloat(s.shop.longitude)
            );

          fullBounds.extend(point);
        });
      map.fitBounds(fullBounds);
```

The problem is some of the markers lay behind the custom control and are not visible. I was wondering if there's a way of telling the map to make the 5 shops visible not just on the whole map, but a specific area of the map. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656743/how-to-offset-the-center-point-in-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: Thanks, it helped to design a solution. I will post the full solution as an answer asap.

Comment: Did you ever get a good solution to this?

Comment: @MaxFavilli It's been more than a year... Still no solution?