# How to convert from (x, y) screen coordinates to LatLng (Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing an application using Google Maps and Leap Motion and what I want right now, and I am a bit stuck, is a way to convert (x, y) screen coordinates into a Google Maps LatLng object.

I want to achieve this in order to start, for example, a panorama (Street View) at the point where the user is pointing with the Leap Motion.

I know about the presence of fromPointToLatLng function, but I have no clue what is the right approach in using it and how can I translate my x and y coordinates into lat lng variables.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: I also thought about simulating a click event or so, but simply triggering a mouse event with javascript will not trigger the right google maps event, since they defined their own events...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some research and some fails I came up with a solution.
Following the documentation from this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#WorldCoordinates) I found out that the google Points are computed in the range of x:[0-256], y:[0-256] (a tile being 256x256 pixels) and the (0,0) point being the leftmost point of the map (check the link for more information).

However, my approach is as it follows:

- having the x and y coordinates (which are coordinates on the screen - on the map) I computed the percentage where the x and y coordinates were placed in response to the div containing the map (in my case, the hole window)
- computed the NortEast and SouthWest LatLng bounds of the (visible) map
- converted the bounds in google Points
- computed the new lat and lng, in google points, with the help of the boundaries and percentage of x and y
- converted back to lat lng

  ```
    // retrieve the lat lng for the far extremities of the (visible) map
    var latLngBounds = map.getBounds();
    var neBound = latLngBounds.getNorthEast();
    var swBound = latLngBounds.getSouthWest();

    // convert the bounds in pixels
    var neBoundInPx = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(neBound);
    var swBoundInPx = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(swBound);

    // compute the percent of x and y coordinates related to the div containing the map; in my case the screen
    var procX = x/window.innerWidth;
    var procY = y/window.innerHeight;

    // compute new coordinates in pixels for lat and lng;
    // for lng : subtract from the right edge of the container the left edge, 
    // multiply it by the percentage where the x coordinate was on the screen
    // related to the container in which the map is placed and add back the left boundary
    // you should now have the Lng coordinate in pixels
    // do the same for lat
    var newLngInPx = (neBoundInPx.x - swBoundInPx.x) * procX + swBoundInPx.x;
    var newLatInPx = (swBoundInPx.y - neBoundInPx.y) * procY + neBoundInPx.y;

    // convert from google point in lat lng and have fun :)
    var newLatLng = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(newLngInPx, newLatInPx));
  ```

Hope this solution will help someone out also! :)

Answer (score 44):

```js
function latLng2Point(latLng, map) {
  var topRight = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
  var bottomLeft = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getSouthWest());
  var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
  var worldPoint = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
  return new google.maps.Point((worldPoint.x - bottomLeft.x) * scale, (worldPoint.y - topRight.y) * scale);
}

function point2LatLng(point, map) {
  var topRight = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
  var bottomLeft = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getSouthWest());
  var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
  var worldPoint = new google.maps.Point(point.x / scale + bottomLeft.x, point.y / scale + topRight.y);
  return map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(worldPoint);
}
```

Comment: Yup, it works! Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: i'm building overlay on map, how can you get pixel value based map element

Comment: just to be clear this gives  Mercator projection point not dom pixel value

Comment: this works very well, but if you're using a Google vector map and that map has been rotated (modified heading), is there any way to take that into account? otherwise the returned lat-lng values will be incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

Check out the easy solution(v3):

```
map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(marker.position);
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Projection

Comment: does x and y represent pixel value on map that you could use to place some other html element or is it something else

Comment: `'map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint returns normalized values, between 0 and 255'`

Answer (score 2):

Adding an alternate solution based on an existing SO question code, despite the original poster found a solution.

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656743/how-to-offset-the-center-point-in-google-maps-api-v3/10666030#10666030) we can find the necessary part for Google Maps API v3 to do the conversion. It focuses on repositioning the center of the map. Modifying it to read the position from the screen requires calculating the difference of the screen coordinates from the screen center.

I renamed the function for the sake of this example to pixelOffsetToLatLng and changed it to return the position (other than that, not too different from the code in the answer above):

```
function pixelOffsetToLatLng(offsetx,offsety) {
  var latlng = map.getCenter();
  var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
  var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(
      map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(),
      map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng()
  );

  var worldCoordinateCenter = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latlng);
  var pixelOffset = new google.maps.Point((offsetx/scale) || 0,(offsety/scale) ||0);

  var worldCoordinateNewCenter = new google.maps.Point(
      worldCoordinateCenter.x - pixelOffset.x,
      worldCoordinateCenter.y + pixelOffset.y
  );

  var latLngPosition = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(worldCoordinateNewCenter);

  return latLngPosition;
}
```

To call it, you need to pass the X and Y coordinates that you have on the web page element:

```
  var x = mapElement.offsetWidth / 2 - screenPositionX;
  var y = screenPositionY - mapElement.offsetHeight / 2;
  pixelOffsetToLatLng(x,y);
```

For the leap.js side, you just need to map the leap.js coordinates to the web page, either by experimenting or by using the screen-position plugin that works like this:

```
var $handCursor = $('#hand-cursor'); // using jQuery here, not mandatory though

Leap.loop(function(frame) {
  if (frame.hands.length > 0) {
    var hand = frame.hands[0];
    $handCursor.css({
      left: hand.screenPosition()[0] + 'px',
      top: hand.screenPosition()[1] + 'px'
    });

    if ((hand.grabStrength >= 0.6 && lastGrabStrength < 0.6)) {
      var x = mapElement.offsetWidth / 2 - hand.screenPosition()[0];
      var y = hand.screenPosition()[1] - mapElement.offsetHeight / 2;
      map.setCenter(pixelOffsetToLatLng(x, y));
    }
  }
}).use('screenPosition', {
  scale: 0.5
});
```

Here's a Codepen example on how to read the coordinates using Leap.js in 2D environment:
http://codepen.io/raimo/pen/pKIko

You can center the Google Maps view using your mouse or by grabbing your hand over the Leap Motion Controller (see the red "cursor" for visual cue).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Google has decided to make life easier.

Here is the built-in solution:

`Point point = googleMap.getProjection.toScreenLocation(latLng)`

`LatLng latlng = googleMap.getProjection.fromScreenLocation(point)`

Answer (score 0):

A [`MapCanvasProjection`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#MapCanvasProjection) object provides a method called `fromContainerPixelToLatLng` which does exactly what you need. However, the only way to obtain an `MapCanvasProjection` object is by implementing a `OverlayView`. I use a dummy overlay for this purpose:

```
    // Create dummy overlay so that we can access MapCanvasProjection
    let overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    overlay.draw = function(){};
    overlay.onAdd = function() {
        this.projectionAvailable = true;
    };
    overlay.onRemove = function() {};
    overlay.setMap(map);
```

Then later whenever you need to convert from screen coordinates to lat,lng:

```
    let x = screen_x_coordinate_relative_to_map_div
    let y = screen_y_coordinate_relative_to_map_div
    if(overlay.projectionAvailable) {
        let projection = overlay.getProjection();
        let divPixel = new google.maps.Point(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
        let latLng = projection.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(divPixel);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to know `(x0,y0)` of the center of your map element, `(lat0,lng0)` of the map center, and the ratio `r` of degrees per pixel, corresponding to the Map's Zoom level. Then

```
lat(y) = lat0 + r(y-y0)
lng(x) = lng0 + r(x-x0)
```

Note that this is a simplified linearized model, working for maps showing small areas.

Comment: What do you mean by degrees/pixel? How may I compute this?
I know the size of the screen, the resolution, the zoom level as well, and as far as I know a tile is 256px, but I don't know the maths behind it, and I'm not sure what are you trying to say by degrees/pixel.

Comment: LatLng coordinates are in degrees. `r` is the ratio coordinates per pixel. You have to find it for your zoom level. It is a simplified linearization model, working for maps showing small areas.