# Convert (x, y) pixel coordinates in google.maps.Point

Tags: google-maps, math, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to find out the LatLng based on my x,y pixel coordinates (and of course map options, such as zoom and center).

In order to do so, I posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219346/how-to-convert-from-x-y-screen-coordinates-to-latlng-google-maps/) and someone came up with this solution, from this [post](http://qfox.nl/notes/116):

```
/**
* @param {google.maps.Map} map
* @param {google.maps.Point} point
* @param {int} z
* @return {google.maps.LatLng}
*/
var pointToLatlng = function(map, point, z){
    var scale = Math.pow(2, z);
    var normalizedPoint = new google.maps.Point(point.x / scale, point.y / scale);
    var latlng = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(normalizedPoint);
    return latlng; 
};
```

As you can notice from the code sample, the function uses as argument a google.maps.Point, therefore I need to convert my screen pixel coordinate into a google.maps.Point and I have no clue how, since their documentation of the API is not quite verbose...

Can you please help me? Or am I missing something on the way?

Comment: new google.maps.Point(xcoord, ycoord);

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work right.. What I've done is printed out the x,y,and new google.maps.Point(x,y), result --> x: 651, y: 330, GooglePoint: (651.3705905079842, 330.8688089251518).... On the other hand I printed out the x,y of the center of the map and used map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getCenter()), result --> xCenter: 683, yCenter: 333, center: (144.90250292629668, 90.19672891441452)... You can clearly see the difference. There has to be something with the zoom level, screen size, resolution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and some fails I came up with a solution.
Following the documentation from this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#WorldCoordinates) I found out that the google Points are computed in the range of x:[0-256], y:[0-256] (a tile being 256x256 pixels) and the (0,0) point being the leftmost point of the map (check the link for more information).

However, my approach is as it follows:

- having the x and y coordinates (which are coordinates on the screen - on the map) I computed the percentage where the x and y coordinates were placed in response to the div containing the map (in my case, the hole window)
- computed the NortEast and SouthWest LatLng bounds of the (visible) map
- converted the bounds in google Points
- computed the new lat and lng, in google points, with the help of the boundaries and percentage of x and y

  ```
    // retrieve the lat lng for the far extremities of the (visible) map
    var latLngBounds = map.getBounds();
    var neBound = latLngBounds.getNorthEast();
    var swBound = latLngBounds.getSouthWest();

    // convert the bounds in pixels
    var neBoundInPx = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(neBound);
    var swBoundInPx = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(swBound);

    // compute the percent of x and y coordinates related to the div containing the map; in my case the screen
    var procX = x/window.innerWidth;
    var procY = y/window.innerHeight;

    // compute new coordinates in pixels for lat and lng;
    // for lng : subtract from the right edge of the container the left edge, 
    // multiply it by the percentage where the x coordinate was on the screen
    // related to the container in which the map is placed and add back the left boundary
    // you should now have the Lng coordinate in pixels
    // do the same for lat
    var newLngInPx = (neBoundInPx.x - swBoundInPx.x) * procX + swBoundInPx.x;
    var newLatInPx = (swBoundInPx.y - neBoundInPx.y) * procY + neBoundInPx.y;
    var finalResult = new google.maps.Point(newLngInPx, newLatInPx);
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an overlay that draws nothing in order to get at the super valuable function, fromContainerPixelToLatLng()

```
var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {}; // empty function required
overlay.setMap(map);

var coordinates = overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(
    new google.maps.Point(x, y)
);

console.log(coordinates.lat + ", " + coordinates.lng);
```