# google maps fromDivPixelToLatLng unexpected results

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, gis

I am currently working on google maps. I came across this method `fromDivPixelToLatLng` which according to documentation converts Pixel coordinates to Latitude and Longitude. My question is how does `fromDivPixelToLatLng` work I mean which coordinate system it follows. Please see my comments in code sample below

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    title: '0, 0',
    position: overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // converts into such a lat and lng that marker is right in
      //middle of screen which lead me to believe that it was following cartesian coordinate
    )
  });



new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    title: '100, 100',
    position: overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(
      new google.maps.Point(100, 100) // i was expecting to be 100px right from center and 
       //100px away from top but instead it's draw in fourth quadrant
    )
  });
```

[Here is fiddle if you want to try it yourself.](https://jsfiddle.net/bfuj49ec/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want [`fromContainerPixelToLatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#MapCanvasProjection.fromContainerPixelToLatLng):

> fromContainerPixelToLatLng(pixel[, nowrap])
>   Parameters: 
>   pixel:  Point optional
>   nowrap:  boolean optional
>   Return Value:  LatLng optional
>   Computes the geographical coordinates from pixel coordinates in the **map's container.**

- `Point(0,0)` is the upper left corner of the `<div>` that contains the `google.maps.Map`
- `Point(100,100)` is down and right 100 pixels from the upper left corner.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4p8h7xLd/5/)

While [`fromDivPixelToLatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#MapCanvasProjection.fromDivPixelToLatLng) (from the documentation):

> Computes the geographical coordinates from pixel coordinates in the div that holds the draggable map.

(which is different from the "map's container", which is what `fromContainerPixelToLatLng` uses)

**code snippet:**

```js
function drawMarkers() {
  var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    title: '0, 0',
    position: overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(0, 0))
  });
  marker0.addListener('click', function(e) {
    var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    iw.setContent("Point(0,0)")
    iw.open(map, marker0);
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker0, 'click');
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    title: '100, 100',
    position: overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(100, 100))
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function(e) {
    var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    iw.setContent("Point(100,100)")
    iw.open(map, marker);
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
}

function draw() {
  var mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(map.getBounds().getSouthWest(),
    this.map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
  projection = overlay.getProjection();
  var tr = new google.maps.LatLng(mapBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
    bounds.getNorthEast().lng());
  var bl = new google.maps.LatLng(mapBounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
    mapBounds.getSouthWest().lng());
}

function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  /* marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  }); */
  overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  overlay.draw = function() {};
  overlay.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="drawMarkers()">
  Draw Markers</button>
</button>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Thats what I figured. But I want to know what return values from `fromDivPixelToLatLng` mean? Are these values in cartesian coordinate or something else.

Comment: From the documentation ["Computes the geographical coordinates from pixel coordinates in the div that holds the draggable map."](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#MapCanvasProjection.fromDivPixelToLatLng) (which is different from the "map's container", which is what `fromContainerPixelToLatLng` uses)

Comment: whats the difference between the div and map container?

Answer (score 0):

Google Map Pixels are probably not what you think in terms of real web page pixels. Maps have multiple coordinate systems, from Lat/Lng, to Tiles, to Map "Pixels" (relative to zoom); none of which are actual HTML pixels.

You might want to use this instead:

```
var coordinates = overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(
    new google.maps.Point(x, y)
);
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28037006/1060646)

I played with your fiddle and added a new marker using this, and it put it in the top/left of your DIV as you would expect:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    title: '0, 0 new',
    position: overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(
        new google.maps.Point(0,0)
    )
  });
```

More info on Map and Tile coordinates:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/coordinates

Comment: Thanks I know about `fromContainerPixelToLatLng`. But I want to know what return values from `fromDivPixelToLatLng` mean? Are these values in cartesian coordinate or something else. Basically I want to get mental model for values from `fromDivPixelToLatLng`.