# find closest point in polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I have an android app using google maps API.
After draw a polyline I want to find,from a know position, the closest point(LatLng) in polyline. Anyone knows how to do that with google maps api? I cannot find nothing.

Thanks

Comment: If you have the poly line locations in LatLng and a known position in LatLng - simply calculate closest point to all of them - and choose the one with smallest distance.

Comment: The problem is I only have the minimum number of vertex of the polyline (wich I use for creating the line) and i may also want the intermediate points.

Comment: If I understood correctly, calculating distance from a point to a line should give you such an intermediate point you need. Maybe there's a misunderstanding on my behalf though.

Comment: But how I can calculate the distance? I can access only to line vertex or to all?

Answer (score 0):

Given points on a flat surface, here is a useful function I wrote:

```
var Places = {
    /**
     * Use this method to calculate the closest point on a polyline
     * @method closest
     * @static
     * @param {Object} point
     * @param {Number} point.x
     * @param {Number} point.y 
     * @param {Array} polyline an array of objects that contain "x" and "y" properties
     * @return {Object} contains properties "index", "x", "y", "distance", "fraction"
     */
    closest: function(point, polyline) {
        var x = point.x;
        var y = point.y;
        var closest = null;
        var distance = null;
        for (var i=1, l=polyline.length; i<l; i++) {
            var a = polyline[i-1].x;
            var b = polyline[i-1].y;
            var c = polyline[i].x;
            var d = polyline[i].y;
            var n = (c-a)*(c-a) + (d-b)*(d-b);
            var frac = n ? ((x-a)*(c-a) + (y-b)+(d-b)) / n : 0;
            var e = a + (c-a)*frac;
            var f = b + (d-b)*frac;
            var dist = Math.sqrt((x-e)*(x-e) + (y-f)(y-f));
            if (distance === null || distance > dist) {
                distance = dist;
                closest = {
                    index: i,
                    x: e,
                    y: f,
                    distance: dist,
                    fraction: frac
                };
            }
        }
        return closest;
    }
}
```

If you want to be more exact, you should use the map's `Projection` object methods to convert the latlng to points on a map and back, before using this function. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219346/how-to-convert-from-x-y-screen-coordinates-to-latlng-google-maps).

However, if your polyline is within a small area like driving for less than 5 hours, then the above function should be good enough to use with the x = latitude, y = longitude directly, since to a close approximation, locally a patch of the Earth's surface is flat.