# How to fix marker on google map and move map?

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-maps, google-latitude

I've done current location show on google map, but I want to fix marker in center on the map when selected "autoPlace city" and then this location is shown on a google map.

My code is below:

```
public class PostAdsFragmentFifth extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = PostAdsFragmentFifth.class.getSimpleName();
private CustomTextView tvBackBtn;
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment;
private GoogleMap mMap;
Address address;
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Marker marker;
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_post_slide5, container, false);
    checkGpsEnabled();
    setGooglePlaces();
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    tvBackBtn = (CustomTextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvBack);
    tvBackBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tvBackBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    checkPermissions();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.tvBack:
            MixPanelEvents.addMixPanelEvents(getActivity(), "Pet Address for Back");

            if (getUserVisibleHint())
                ((PostAdsActivity) getActivity()).gotoNext(4);
            break;

    }
}

private void setGooglePlaces() {
    autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
    autocompleteFragment.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.address_hint_toast));

    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
            .build();
    autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

            address = new Address();
            address.setLatitude(place.getLatLng().latitude);
            address.setLongitude(place.getLatLng().longitude);
            address.setAddress(place.getAddress().toString());
            address.setLandmark(place.getName().toString());
            PostAdsActivity.postData.setAddress(address);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            LogUtils.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
}


protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        double lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        if (lat != 0 && lng != 0) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 16.0f));
            convertLocationToAddress(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            if (marker != null) {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }

    }
}

private void checkPermissions() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ArrayList<String> permissons = new ArrayList<>();
        permissons.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        permissons.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        String[] items = permissons.toArray(new String[permissons.size()]);
        requestPermissions(items, 4);
    } else {
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mMap = googleMap;
                setUpMap();
                buildGoogleApiClient();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    if (Utility.isAppInstalled(getActivity(), "com.google.android.apps.maps")) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                LatLng currentLocation = marker.getPosition();
                convertLocationToAddress(currentLocation);
                return false;
            }
        });
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                LatLng currentLocation = marker.getPosition();
                convertLocationToAddress(currentLocation);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {

                LogUtils.e("TAG", mMap.getCameraPosition().target.toString());
                convertLocationToAddress(mMap.getCameraPosition().target);
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(mMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude, mMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude))
                        .title("Marker")
                        .draggable(true)
                        .snippet("Location")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            }
        });


    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 4) {
        for (int a = 0; a < permissions.length; a++) {
            if (grantResults[a] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                continue;
            }
            switch (permissions[a]) {
                case Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION:
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                            mMap = googleMap;
                            setUpMap();
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION:
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                            mMap = googleMap;
                            setUpMap();
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                    });
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}

private void convertLocationToAddress(LatLng latLong) {
    try {

        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<android.location.Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLong.latitude, latLong.longitude, 1);

        LogUtils.d("Address", addresses.toString());
        /*address.setAddress(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
        if (addresses.get(0).getLocality() != null) {
            address.setCity(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
        } else {
            address.setCity("");
        }
        if (addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() != null) {
            address.setState(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
        } else {
            address.setState("");
        }
        address.setLatitude(latLong.latitude);
        address.setLongitude(latLong.longitude);
        if (addresses.get(0).getPostalCode() != null) {
            // address.setPinCode(addresses.get(0).getPostalCode());
        }*/


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void checkGpsEnabled() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;
    try {
        gps_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        network_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.location_gps_alretDialog_tittle));
            dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.location_gps_alretDialog_msg));
            dialog.setPositiveButton(this.getResources().getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    MixPanelEvents.addMixPanelEvents(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.location_gps_alretDialog_tittle));
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton(this.getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    paramDialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Simply make a fixed icon center in the layout . programmatically make coordinates center when on click on GPS

Comment: Whats exactly the error when you tried the above code

Comment: how to fixed  marker in center on google map.

Comment: You can find an answer to your question in this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39821038/create-overlay-imageview-animation-google-map/39971868#39971868

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add your marker as a view and overlay it on top of the map.
Your layout file can look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/map_container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="com.example.mapstest.MapsActivity" />

  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/pin_view"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/pin"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

and later set this way

```
public void moveCamera(double lat, double lng) {
    CameraPosition cameraPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .zoom(10).bearing(0).tilt(0).build();
    mapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPos), null);
}
```

or 
if your using a MapFragment add the marker to the fragment activity

check this :

[android How to move a map under a marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346206/android-how-to-move-a-map-under-a-marker)

Comment: but I'm use in xml
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_10dp" />