# Display pin on the Image of the map

Tags: c#, image, coordinates

I have image which displays Map. I know image size and every corner coordination. Eg. North-West and South-East corners.
Now I want to pin an icon for the City. (again I know coordinates).

How can I convert coorditionate into pixels x and y? I'm using C#.

So far I was doing percentage calculation. But it didn't work with Latitude very well. I assume this is because of the Earth shape?

What I was doing so far.
Top-Left image corner is -9.840779780566143,112.977570075 (North-West)
Bottom-Right conver is -44.52721413845025,154.28616382500002 (South-East)

Image width is: 937px, height: 930px

Using Syndey coordinates for the pin: -33.865143, 151.209900

1. Calculating percentage position: LatPercentage = ((SydneyLat - NorthWestLat) / (SoutEastLat- NorthWestLat))
2. Calculating position within the image: ImageHight * LatPercentage

This almost works for edge places. eg. close to 0% and 100% of the height. But anything close to 50% is far from it's correct position.

How should I improve the calculation?

Comment: No map is perfect, it is impossible to represent a fragment of the globe on a flat map.  Each map is distorted in some way.  You would need to know the type of projection used to create your map and then translate the coordinates to x/y position on the map using an appropriate algorithm.

Comment: What if my map has same proportion as google map. Eg. I do print screen. Would that help?

Comment: If you are only using Google Maps, then you should easily be able to find how to do it, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25252731/780815

Comment: Sorry not be be clear. I'm not using google maps. Just saying that I can create my map image to be distorted in the same way. My map is a picture of Australia. I can say designer to have the same propertion as if I print screened from google maps. Original idea was to have something like Google static map API, but using our own map image. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start then add pin to the image on the server. And return back to the user.