# Calculating New Map Bounds from an Overlay Div

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In this example, you can see the `oldBounds` (aka my initial bounds) when the map is loaded. But how can I get the actual `newBounds` when the `#panel` is overlaid on top of the map? Try clicking the Launch Panel button and see: http://jsfiddle.net/3npoupdL/

I guess one approach could be to resize the `#map-canvas` once the `#panel` is shown?

Looking for bounds that are not covered by the panel once it is opened.

Here's my JS code:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.879535, -87.624333),
        scrollwheel: false
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var oldBounds = document.getElementById("old-bounds");
    var newBounds = document.getElementById("new-bounds");

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
        oldBounds.innerHTML = "old bounds: " + map.getBounds();
    });

    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.onclick = function () {
        $("#panel").addClass("show");
        newBounds.innerHTML = "new bounds: " + map.getBounds();
    };
}
```

Comment: You mean bounds as the part of the map that is not covered by the panel?

Comment: @davidkonrad Yes that's correct. That's what I am looking for.

Comment: related question: [How to offset the center point in Google maps api V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656743/how-to-offset-the-center-point-in-google-maps-api-v3) (not about getting the bounds, but about offsetting the center)

Comment: simliar question (but not answered): [Gmap LatLngBounds with an offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835119/gmap-latlngbounds-with-an-offset)

Comment: How about adjusting your code using this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/rat1fkkc/?

Comment: @eugensunic That's interesting. Will have a look. But my panel appears after clicking the button. This map already has the panel positioned on the left. Thank you though. Checking the code.