# google map change offsetCenter on page width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I am trying to make a this  [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j04w.png) 
my code is not working as i expect ..
if the old width is bigger than the new width and offset Center -50
and if the old width is smaller than the new width and offset Center 50

**the offset Center works with out the if
but that means the if the user resizes the window the offset Center will be  50 or -50 every time the user resizes**

**the rectangles on the map is for covering the names only**
html

css

```
#map{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

js

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&callback=initMap">
</script>


<script>
function oh_ow() {
        var oh = $(window).height();
        var ow = $(window).width();
        return ow;
}    
    var old_w = oh_ow()
    alert(old_w );

        alert(ow);
    function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: 62.26393, lng: 82.386004};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });



function offsetCenter(latlng, offsetx, offsety) {

    // latlng is the apparent centre-point
    // offsetx is the distance you want that point to move to the right, in pixels
    // offsety is the distance you want that point to move upwards, in pixels
    // offset can be negative
    // offsetx and offsety are both optional

    var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());

    var worldCoordinateCenter = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latlng);
    var pixelOffset = new google.maps.Point((offsetx/scale) || 0,(offsety/scale) ||0);

    var worldCoordinateNewCenter = new google.maps.Point(
        worldCoordinateCenter.x - pixelOffset.x,
        worldCoordinateCenter.y + pixelOffset.y
    );

    var newCenter = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(worldCoordinateNewCenter);

    map.setCenter(newCenter);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {

//---------------------------------------------    
var rtime;
var timeout = false;
var delta = 200;
$(window).resize(function() {
    rtime = new Date();
    if (timeout === false) {
        timeout = true;

        setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
    }
});
function resizeend() {
    if (new Date() - rtime < delta) {
        setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
    } else {
        timeout = false;
          var nh = $(window).height();
          var nw = $(window).width();
          //alert("old"+old_w);
          //alert("new"+nw);
       if(nw > old_w){
            offsetCenter(map.getCenter(),50,-0);
        }else if(nw < old_w){
            offsetCenter(map.getCenter(),-50,-0);
        }


    }               
}    
//---------------------------------------------    
});





}



</script>
```

what i wont is a responsive virgin of [How to offset the center point in Google maps api V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656743/how-to-offset-the-center-point-in-google-maps-api-v3)

please can someone help

Comment: You requirement is not clear. Are you trying to center lock the geo location `{lat: 25.26393, lng: 55.386004}` ?

Comment: I wont the marker to be on the right side when the page loads and and if resized

Comment: the responsive virgin of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656743/how-to-offset-the-center-point-in-google-maps-api-v3@ Diode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, I think that it is something that can be achieved using `setCenter`, `panTo` and `panBy` methods.

```
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {
    lat: 25.26393,
    lng: 55.386004
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });

  var winWidth = $(window).width();
  panMap();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    map.setCenter(uluru);
    panMap();
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    map.panTo(uluru);
    panMap();
  });

  function panMap(xChange){
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    if(winWidth > 671){
      map.panBy(xChange || -170, 0);
    }
  }

}
```

You can adjust `-170` to get the desired position.

Demo here : https://jsbin.com/fasawofofa/1/edit?html,output

Comment: yes great ,but  how to set it to center if the page width is under 671px; @Diode

Comment: I have added a condition for that. Please see the new answer