# Shift the center of google map to right Angular 2

Tags: google-maps, angular, angular-google-maps

I am using [angular2-google-map](https://angular-maps.com/)

I want to shift the center to map to left.

**what it is right now**
[image: What it is righ now]

**what I want**
[image: what I want]

**the html**

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="center.lat" [longitude]="center.long">
    <sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="let h of mapData?.list" [latitude]="h.lat" [longitude]="h.lang">
        <sebm-google-map-info-window [maxWidth]="300">
            <strong>{{h.info}}</strong>
        </sebm-google-map-info-window>
    </sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

**Component.ts file**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'google-map',
    templateUrl: './google-map.component.html',
    providers: [MapDataService]
})

export class googleMapComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    center:any;
    @Input() mapData: Array<Object>;
    public constructor(private mapService: MapDataService) {
        this.center = {};
        this.center['lat'] = 28.457523;
        this.center['long'] = 77.026344;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Note: Image are taken from [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533717/how-i-can-left-align-the-google-maps) which has the same issues(but in simple google map)

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.browserWidth = window.innerWidth;
  this.lngDiff = this.browserWidth * .000335;
}
```

And update: `this.center['long'] = 77.026344;` to `this.center['long'] = 77.026344+this.lngDiff;`

---

**Long Answer:**

I had to do something similar where I had to offset the map to the right (but keep it centered in the right half of the browser). In order to do this I manually centered the map in the right half of the screen where I wanted it based on 3 different browser widths `1920px, 1280px, and 790px`.

The difference of the longitude on the map was different for all three points. For `1920px` the longitude of the map needed to be off-center by `.65`, for `1280px` the difference was `.43` and for `790px` the difference was `.26`.

I then did a little bit of math to figure out what all three points had in common (I had to solve for x).

`1920 * x = .65`, `1280 * x = .43`, and `790 * x = .26`.

Because these points weren't exactly the midpoint I was looking for, I averaged the result of all of those points. What I got was `.000335` which is the number that you're multiplying the browser width by.

You can now add `this.lngDiff` to your longitude to offset the map to the left or subtract to offset the map to the right.

[The result is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEZZA.png)