# Detect waypoint click on DirectionsRenderer marker in Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In the Google Maps API v3, how can I get the waypoint markers from the DirectionsRenderer in order to add click events to them (such as a delete menu).

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem right now. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I don't think there is a solution with the current state of the Google Maps API. Someone should submit a feature request. I've thought about a potential workaround, but haven't had the time to pursue it.

Comment: @lashleigh: This enhancement would allow code to easily be written to solve the problem. Go ahead and star it, if you like: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2141

Comment: Thanks, I'll add my name to the list.

Answer (score 5):

Until a better solution can be found here is the work around that I have employed.  The basic idea is to put your own marker on top of the waypoints and bind a click event listener to your marker. I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3AdSG/) demonstrating the idea.

It definitely isn't perfect, but with a custom icon instead of the default marker it could look sort of natural.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, which doesn't involve putting new markers on the map, would be to detect DOM click events on the map widget. The idea is simple. When a click is detected:

1. convert all waypoints' LatLng coordinates to coordinates on the screen (or, in fact, on the map widget) using [MapCanvasProjection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538681/how-to-call-fromlatlngtodivpixel-in-google-maps-api-v3)
2. calculate distances between waypoints and the point clicked. If user clicked close enough to any of the waypoints (the distance is lower than the radius of a waypoint icon) - display a menu for that point

I coded a [complete solution in java for gwt](http://pastebin.com/9WuP8NUe). It should be pretty straightforward to get it translated into javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a click event on a waypoint, you can create it on a marker, and assign it a high z-index so it overlays the waypoint.

1. Create the single markers and assign the a high z-index

```js
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map:map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(1.99, 2.99),
    });
    marker.setZIndex(999);
```

2. Add a listener to the markers

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event){
      alert(marker.title);
    });
```

3. And now create the waypoints.