# Add click eventlisteners to directionService endpoint markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am wanting to be able to reference and/or attach click event listeners to the A and B end point markers from a window.google.maps.DirectionsService call.

I am aware you can surpress these markers and create your own (all stackoverflows related to this suggested that. I dont want it), but you lose the functionality of being able to drag the markers and have it calculate a new route based on where you drag the endpoints.

The main thing I want to do is override the default infoWindow and display my own custom one. The first step is being able to hook into the markers though. Simply just be able to trigger a click event is not enough, I need access to the event handler to override.

Here is an example of draggable markers: http://jsbin.com/mekapadigo/1/edit?html,output

I do not need/want the panel on the right, but I noticed that there is an event listening on the A and B markers using that, so that suggestions maybe this is possible.

Comment: [https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2141](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2141) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630341/detect-waypoint-click-on-directionsrenderer-marker-in-google-maps-v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630341/detect-waypoint-click-on-directionsrenderer-marker-in-google-maps-v3) would suggest that there isn't a direct way to access the markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the version with markers attached to the endpoints that display an info window when clicked.  The marker positions and waypoints are feed back into the directions service when the markers are dragged.  The request was throttled so it doesn't go over the query limit of 10 per second.  Markers should be moved back onto the route after the route is calculated (left as an exercise for you).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Draggable directions</title>
 <style>
  html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
 function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom: 10,
   center: {lat: 40.6, lng: -73.9}
  });

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
   draggable: true,
   map: map,
   suppressMarkers: true
  });

  var waypoints = [];
  var markerStart = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: {lat: 40.851246, lng: -73.875218},
   map: map,
   draggable:true
  });
  var infowindowStart = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: "Marker Start Info Window"
  });
  markerStart.addListener('click', function() {
   infowindowStart.open(map, markerStart);
  });

  var markerEnd = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: {lat: 40.831916, lng: -73.888947},
   map: map,
   draggable:true
  });
  var infowindowEnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: "Marker End Info Window"
  });
  markerEnd.addListener('click', function() {
   infowindowEnd.open(map, markerEnd);
  });


  var redisplay = _.throttle(function() {
   displayRoute(markerStart, markerEnd, directionsService, directionsDisplay, waypoints);
  }, 200);
  google.maps.event.addListener(markerStart, 'drag', redisplay);
  google.maps.event.addListener(markerEnd, 'drag', redisplay);

  directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
   var directions = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
   waypoints = directions.request.waypoints;
  });

  displayRoute(markerStart, markerEnd, directionsService, directionsDisplay, waypoints);

 }

 function displayRoute(markerStart, markerEnd, service, display, waypoints) {
  service.route({
   origin: markerStart.getPosition(),
   destination: markerEnd.getPosition(),
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
   waypoints: waypoints,
   avoidTolls: true
  }, function(response, status) {
   if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    waypoints = response.request.waypoints;
    display.setDirections(response);
   } else {
    console.log('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
   }
  });
 }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create your own markers you do not loose the ability to have the route re-calculated when you drag the end-points. I think that the example at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable does what you are looking for.

Here is some modified code from that example.  You can listen on the 'directions_changed' event, and display whatever you like in the side panel:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Draggable directions</title>
 <style>
  html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
   height: 100%;
   float: left;
   width: 63%;
   height: 100%;
  }
  #right-panel {
   float: right;
   width: 34%;
   height: 100%;
  }
  #right-panel {
   font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
   line-height: 30px;
   padding-left: 10px;
  }

  #right-panel select, #right-panel input {
   font-size: 15px;
  }

  #right-panel select {
   width: 100%;
  }

  #right-panel i {
   font-size: 12px;
  }

  .panel {
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="right-panel">
 <p>Total Distance: <span id="total"></span></p>
 <p>Your custom information would go here...</p>
</div>
<script>
 // Modified from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable
 // For so question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816222/add-click-eventlisteners-to-directionservice-endpoint-markers
 function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom: 8,
   center: {lat: 40.6, lng: -73.9}
  });

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
   draggable: true,
   map: map,
  });

  directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
   // This is where you would do your custom processing
   computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
  });
  displayRoute({lat: 40.763637, lng:-73.972238}, {lat: 40.849651, lng:-73.877270}, directionsService,
   directionsDisplay);
 }

 function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
  service.route({
   origin: origin,
   destination: destination,
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
   avoidTolls: true
  }, function(response, status) {
   if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    display.setDirections(response);
   } else {
    alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
   }
  });
 }

 function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var total = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
   total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
  }
  total = total / 1000;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
 }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `directions_changed` is only triggered when one of their markers are dragged. If google's markers are suppressed and replaced with custom ones, the `directions_changed` event would not trigger because there is no event I can attach to my markers to say "Upon drag, these will change the directions".

Granted, you could have a drag event on normal markers and then upon a `drag_end` you could re-run `display.setDirections` but you lose the real-time route being updated as you drag.

The example from the link you post is still using google markers for the end points (which trigger the drag)

Comment: @ParoX - I think that if you feed any waypoints that have been created in the route update back into the route call when you re-calculate with new end-points, your marker move won't result in you loosing anything in your route.  I'll update the code above to illustrate if I have time.