# Getting the x/y coordinates on Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates, geocoding

I've created a custom tiled map using the Google Maps API and have got a click event to show the latitude/longitude values of where has been selected.

Is there any way of getting the x/y coordinates instead either through the Google Maps API or by converting the latitude/longitude values?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapCanvasProjection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call fromLatLngToDivPixel in Google Maps API V3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538681/how-to-call-fromlatlngtodivpixel-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 0):

This is the recipe transfer from latitude/longitude to coordinates:

- You have decimal degrees (-73.9874°) instead of degrees, minutes, and seconds (-73° 59’ 14.64")
- The whole units of degrees will remain the same (-73.9874° longitude, start with 73°)
- Multiply the decimal by 60 (0.9874 * 60 = 59.244)
- The whole number becomes the minutes (59’)
- Take the remaining decimal and multiply by 60. (0.244 * 60 = 14.64)
  The resulting number becomes the seconds (14.64"). Seconds can remain
  as a decimal.
- Take your three sets of numbers and put them
  together, using the symbols for degrees (°), minutes (’), and seconds
  (") (-73° 59’
    14.64" longitude).

Example: latitude/longitude: 10.787331, 106.647095 = coordinates :10°47'14.4"N 106°38'49.5"E